# How to upload an image and view it in the browser?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, filereader

Is there any way to upload an image file from PC and preview it in browser. And it should be cross browser compatible. Filereader is a way, But there are issues with that doing the functionality locally in chrome.

Comment: So what you want to do is allow the user to load a file without submitting it to the server? If so then you should remove the `file-upload` tag to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FormData to send across the image to the server using ajax, get back the source of the image and add an image element to your document with that source when the ajax call returns.

Documentation on FormData - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest/FormData

Comment: But i don't have to do any server call!!! Just upload image locally and it appears as a thumbnail!!!

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing with FileReader? Works fine for me.

Comment: Locally, in chrome, i can't access file data through file reader. While it works fine with firefox!!!!

Comment: works for me in chrome too. are you getting some error? Did you try to debug it?